# Can I do math on LTspice parameters?

Tags: ltspice

[image]

I would expect the voltage source to output 20V but the simulation throws an error instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write {2*V} instead of {V}*2.

Comment: Thanks. When I try 2{V} or 2*{V} it throws an error and sets the voltage to 2 volts instead of the expected 20. So maybe you tried it with `.param V=1` which makes it look like it's correct?

Comment: You are correct. However, the {2*V} seems to work for me and give the correct result also with different values for V. Also without the "=".

Comment: Yep, {2*V} works perfectly.

Comment: While this is a correct answer, it might be worth adding that the curly braces perform evaluation, and all parameter substitution happens before the start of the simulation. Since a voltage source can only accept parameters that are not `time`-dependent, the evaluation must be performed for all the expression that makes the value of the source, therefore the curly braces need to enclose everything in it that needs to be evaluated.