# "*" unknown parameter in LTspice simulation

Tags: ltspice

10000 * exp(3000*(1/298.15 - 1/(t+273.15))),
this expression in LTspice showing "*" as an unknown parameter. How to fix this.

Comment: see if this helps https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594993/can-i-do-math-on-ltspice-parameters

Comment: Have you tried writing it in a different way to get rid of the "*"?

Comment: I tried to write using curly brackets. A simple example as {10k * 20k} works. But when I am writing this whole expression in a curly bracket {10000 * exp(3000*(1/298.15 - 1/(t+273.15)))}, it still shows "*" unknown parameter.

Comment: Have you defined the parameter _t_ somewhere?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Then, that’s where the error is. You should define _t_.

Comment: Hey, Thanks 10000  * exp*(3000(1/298.15 - 1/( temp+273.15))) and then Circuit: * C:\Users\p302617\Documents\LTspiceXVII\Draft2.asc

Error on line 4 : r2 n002 0 10000 * exp*(3000(1/298.15 - 1/( temp+273.15)))
  Unknown parameter "*"

Date: Sun Mar 26 21:38:20 2023
Total elapsed time: 0.029 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 86
method = trap
totiter = 123
traniter = 0
tranpoints = 0
accept = 0
rejected = 0
matrix size = 3
fillins = 0
solver = Normal
Matrix Compiler1:       3 opcodes  0.0/[0.0]/0.0
Matrix Compiler2: 175 bytes object code size  0.0/0.0/[0.0]
 still it shows the error.

Comment: You should post your entire LTspice .ASC file so we can see the whole context.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the spaces first.
LTSpice does not like that in some cases.
For instance when you use a voltage source of "12 V" it complains about "unknown parameter v"